# What is the /usr directory in Linux?

Tags: fhs

FHS-3.0 describes it as:

> Shareable, readonly data. That means that `/usr` should be shareable between various FHS-compliant hosts and must not be written to.

I am a bit confused by what this means. Does this means that the binaries or whatever other files inside should be copy-pasteable onto another machine, and have them function perfectly fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what it means is only that distros shouldn't assume that an installation has sole ownership of `/usr`, not that everything in `/usr` is expected to work with all FHS-compliant systems. I think I have heard of `/usr` being served over the network (via NFS for example) for a bunch of systems running the same distro. Since `/usr` is where the bulk of all installed files reside, this makes for a lot of space savings. Also, I think it's not unusual to have `/usr` a separate filesystem in any case, mounted read-only for additional security, so the "must not be written to" part helps with that as well.

`/etc` can't be shared in this manner - some files, like `/etc/hostname` are necessarily different for each host (though most files in `/etc` can be so shared, I think). Nor can `/var` - it wouldn't make sense to have two services on different systems logging to the same file, for example.